# Amazon Lex using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-lex

How to create multiple intents in Amazon Lex bot using command line interface?

I can generate single intent but I want to add more than one intent at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Operations_Amazon_Lex_Model_Building_Service.html) of Amazon Lex Model Building Service, you can only put **one intent at a time**.
You can write your own code that will put many intents by running multiple commands.